# How come the first while loop keeps looping to collect information? Python

Tags: python, validation, loops, while-loop

The first while loop is there to validate whether the user enters 'p', 'd' or anything else. If the user enters an incorrect input it should ask again and once the information has been collected, the pizza menu should print out, but it loops back to ask for pickup or delivery.

```
import re

pickupCost = 0
deliveryCost = 5

running = True

menu = {}
menu['Pepperoni'] = 9
menu['Hawaiian'] = 9
menu['Cheese'] = 9
menu['Italian'] = 9
menu['Margherita'] = 9
menu['Apricot Chicken'] = 13
menu['BBQ Meatlovers'] = 13
menu['Chicken and Cranberry'] = 13



while running == True:
  delivery = raw_input("please select either p for pickup or d for delivery")
  delivery = delivery.lower()
  if delivery == "p":
    while running == True: #puts code in loop if user enters invalid input#
      customer_name = raw_input("Name: ")
      if not re.match("^[a-zA-Z ]*$", customer_name): #checks that no numbers and symbols are used#
        print "Please only use letters"
      elif len(customer_name) == 0: #checks user doesnt try leaving it empty#
        print "Cannot be left blank"
      elif customer_name == " ":  #checks they don't just push space then enter#
        print "Please enter a valid input"
      else:
        customer_name = customer_name.title()
        break #breaks loop
  elif delivery =="d":
    while running == True: #puts code in loop if user enters invalid input#
      customer_name = raw_input("Name: ")
      if not re.match("^[a-zA-Z ]*$", customer_name):
        print "Please only use letters"
      elif len(customer_name) == 0:
        print "Cannot be left blank"
      elif customer_name == " ":
        print "Please enter a valid input"
      else:
        customer_name = customer_name.title()
        break
    while running == True:
      house_num = raw_input("House Number: ")
      if not re.match("^[0-9]*$", house_num): #checks user only enters numbers
        print "Please only use numbers"
      elif len(house_num) == 0:
        print "Cannot be left blank"
      else:
        break
    while running == True:
      street_name = raw_input("Street Name: ")
      if not re.match("^[a-zA-Z ]*$", street_name):
        print "Please only use letters"
      elif len(street_name) == 0:
        print "Cannot be left blank"
      elif street_name == " ":
        print "Please enter a valid input"
      else:
        street_name = street_name.title()
        break
    while running == True:
      suburb = raw_input("Suburb: ")
      if not re.match("^[a-zA-Z ]*$", suburb):
        print "Please only use letters"
      elif len(suburb) == 0:
        print "Cannot be left blank"
      elif suburb == " ":
        print "Please enter a valid input"
      else:
        suburb = suburb.title()
        break
    while running == True:
      postcode = raw_input("Postcode: ")
      if not re.match("^[0-9]*$", postcode):
        print "Please only use numbers"
      elif len(postcode) == 0:
        print "Cannot be left blank"
      else:
        break
    while running == True:
      city = raw_input("City: ")
      if not re.match("^[a-zA-Z ]*$", city):
        print "Please only use letters"
      elif len(city) == 0:
        print "Cannot be left blank"
      elif city == " ":
        print "Please enter a valid input"
      else:
        city = city.title()
        break
  else:
    print "invalid input"
    break

def print_menu(menu):
    x = 1
    for key in menu:
        print x,key,menu[key]
        x += 1
print_menu(menu)
```

Comment: You're missing a `break` statement at the bottom of your loop body.

Comment: @coldspeed thank you